# Android get results from activities

Tags: java, android

**Activity A** starts **activity B**.

Within activity B I will do some logic and start new **activity C** and at the same time I will finish the **activity B**.

Now how can I get the get the results from **activity C** to **activity A** to update the entries in activity A. ?

Comment: what you want to get in activity A.

Comment: Have you heard of using an intent?  I probably would not choose your current workflow; let activity A's business by finished, then start another activity.

Comment: Say Activity C get the create new product and Activity A hold the list of created products. I need to update the product list. (if the product creation is successful )

Comment: Have you heard of using an intent?  yes. intent can pass data from one activity to another, How onActivityResult works only for immediate activity.

Comment: If your app's state is in an external application (e.g. a Java webapp with a database), then you wouldn't need to pass anything; just sync up with the remote database to get new product information.

Comment: do you want some data from activity B to activity A also??

Comment: @sumit No I dont need data from B to A

Comment: please try using shared preferences to store the value in Activity C and retrieve in target activity.

Comment: if you simply want data from C to A then what's the problem in sending through intent??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities can only receive results from activities they have started directly. If you use `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult()`, Activity A will be able to get a result from Activity B, but it will not be able to get a result from Activity C.

One option is to chain your activity results together. Instead of finishing Activity B when you start Activity C, instead use `startActivityForResult()` in Activity B and leave it running. When Activity C sets a result and finishes, you can handle that in Activity B, set that same result, and finish Activity B so that it gets passed back to Activity A.

```
A --starts--> B --starts--> C
                            |
A <--result-- B <--result-- C
```

Another option is to use some other mechanism for passing information between activities. You could skip using `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`, and perhaps just write the information you need to a database or `SharedPreferences`, and then check for updates in Activity A's `onResume()` or similar.

Comment: OK.  I cannot leave the activity B. I should finish it. Shall we use fragment for the Activity B and C. ..

Comment: In Activity A - start new Activity B- with fragment 1 and based on logic and swap the fragment 1 to 2. and finish the activity B when start finish. ?

Comment: Why do you have to finish it immediately? You can finish it inside `onActivityResult()`, so the user will think that they went A > B > C > A, since they'll never see B resume (even though it does, very briefly).

Comment: Yes.  That is application specific. Have to delete it. cannot allow to go back.

Comment: If you must use activities, and you must finish B immediately, then you won't be able to use `onActivityResult()`. If you can use fragments for B and C, that should work just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Use getter setter to take data from activity C  to activity A

Comment: activity C is the top of the stack and activity A below that. (but activity A started B)

Comment: which kind of data you want in the activity a

Comment: i think you can easily take data from acitivity C to A by using getter setter .

Comment: set the data in the activity C and finish it after that get data in the activity A